# TikZ draw objects with fields

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-pic

How can I draw using TikZ (or other libraries) something like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything, and if so, where does the problem lie?

Comment: I haven't. Don't know how to draw the inner nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way with TikZ, where the structure is built manually. Wrapped it in a macro for convenience, the width of the second column is set to that of the widest entry in the column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,backgrounds}

\newcommand\someboxthingy[3]{
\pgfmathsetmacro\widestentry{max(\widthof{#1},\widthof{#2},\widthof{#3})}
\begin{scope}[
    lcol/.style={anchor=east},
    rcol/.style={anchor=base west,align=left,text width=\widestentry,fill=white,draw=black},
    node distance=4.5ex and 2pt]
\node (from) {From:};
\node [below=of from.east,lcol] (to) {To:};
\node [below=of to.east,lcol] (subj) {Subject:};

\node [right=of from.base east,rcol] (ur) {#1};
\node [right=of to.base east,rcol] {#2};
\node [right=of subj.base east,rcol] {#3};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[fill=black!20,draw=black,fit=(subj)(ur)] {};
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\someboxthingy{Lycke}{Jean}{On the procurement of money}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try your name with the descender. It shows that the alignment of the base lines in a row is not yet correct.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek You're right (of course). Updated to set `text depth` for all the nodes, guess that should fix it.

Comment: (+1) Just for the sender and subject. Even if the code didn't work, this would be worth an upvote ;).

Comment: How can I fix the width of this object? (I want to create a few mail objects, and that all of them will be in the same size)

Comment: @zvisofer Set the `text width` to some specific length instead of `\widestentry`., e.g. `text width=5cm`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No, setting `text depth` does not align the base lines (try with accented upper case letter). Possible solution: Adding `anchor=base west` to `rcol` and using explicit base anchor in `right=of`: `right=of from.base east`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Damn, right again. I did think about using the `base` anchors, but didn't apply it .. But thanks for picking up on my mistakes! Will edit shortly.

Answer (score 4):

You can try with a `matrix` which serve as filled background nodes while inner nodes are drawn or filled according your taste.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[field/.style={draw, fill=white, 
                   minimum height=1cm, text width= 5cm, align=left}]
\matrix (card) [matrix of nodes, draw, fill=gray,
                column 2/.style={nodes=field},  
                column 1/.style={text width=1.5cm, align=right}]
{From: & Chris\\
To: & Albert, Eddy\\
Subject: & FREE OFFER!!!!\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: Still with `matrix` but now inside a `\mybox` command and using `\widestwidth` from [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253149/1952) and some minor adjustments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newcommand{\mybox}[3]{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\widestentry{max(\widthof{#1}, \widthof{#2},\widthof{#3})}
\begin{tikzpicture}[field/.style={draw, fill=white, 
                text width= \widestentry, 
                text depth=\depthof{y}, align=left}]
\matrix (card) [matrix of nodes, row sep=3pt, draw, 
               fill=gray!30, ampersand replacement=\&,
               column 2/.style={nodes=field},  
               column 1/.style={text width=1.2cm, align=right}]
{From: \& {#1}\\ To: \& {#2}\\ Subject: \& {#3}\\};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\mybox{Chris}{Albert, George, Sue}{Let's make a study group} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A solution via a table with the advantage that the width is set automatically to the needed space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{\tabcolsep}
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
  \fcolorbox{black}{lightgray}{%
    \begin{tabular}{
      @{}% margin from outer \fcolorbox
      r
      % vertical line, which is moved to the right
      !{\vrule width\arrayrulewidth\kern-\arrayrulewidth}
      % set cell color:
      >{\columncolor{white}
         [\dimexpr\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax]
         [\tabcolsep]}
      l|
    }   
      \cline{2-2}
      \noalign{\kern\arrayrulewidth}
      From: & Chris\\
      \cline{2-2}
      \addlinespace
      \cline{2-2}
      \noalign{\kern\arrayrulewidth}
      To: & Albert, Eddie\\
      \cline{2-2}
      \addlinespace
      \cline{2-2}
      \noalign{\kern\arrayrulewidth}
      Subject: & Our presentation for class\\
      \cline{2-2}
    \end{tabular}%
  }
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Some tricks are used:

- The outer gray box is set via `\fcolorbox`. Line thickness `\fboxsep` is set to 1 pt. The margin `\fboxsep` is set to `\tabcolsep`.
- The white fields are set via `\columncolor` of package `colortbl`, loaded by option `table` of package `xcolor`.
- `\addlinespace` of package `bookmark` sets additional line space, which
  does not belong to the cells, this avoids white background color and vertical lines in this area.
- The inner frame is done via vertical lines of `tabular` and horizontal lines via `\cline`. The latter has the peculiarity that it does not move down to allow further `\cline` commands. Moving down is important here, otherwise the line would be overprinted by the white cell background color.
  The moving down is achieved by `\noalign{\kern\arrayrulewidth}`.
- The left vertical line is outside the cell by default with ugly corners. Therefore the line is set inside: `!{\vrule\arrayrulewidth\kern-\arrayrulewidth}`. Then the optional arguments of `\cellcolor` need to be specified to avoid the overprint of the left vertical rule.
- The line thickness of the `tabular` rules are set via `\arrayrulewidth`.